# Does Mega Jump download personal data from your iPhone?

Tags: ios, mega-jump

Does anybody know if Mega Jump is one of these free iPhone apps which downloads sensitive personal data from your iPhone?

Is there a site where all the apps are listed where privacy concerns have been reported?

Comment: Mega Jump usually costs $0.99, and GetSet games is a fairly big name on the app store, It's safe to assume they're reputable. I'm positive Mega Jump is secure, but I can't give you a source for this.

Comment: seems that it now is free, thanx for the info ;)

Comment: Yeah, it looks like they're doing a promotion.  I can tell you I've got it and never had a problem with security.

Comment: If you download an app from the official store, "we" should assume they should satisfy security requirements. Now, I'm not an iOS developer so I don't know what is Apple policy but I hope they want to protect our personal data.

Comment: @Gnome You should make your comments an answer so that we can get this off our unanswered list.

Comment: @dierre That's a dangerous assumption. The Wall Street Journal found that many of the top 100 apps in the Apple and Android app stores are [collecting user information](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052748704694004576020083703574602.html).

Comment: I'm sorry but collecting user information is different from protecting our data, as long as you informed the user for what reason your collecting their data and that reason is legit.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note: just because a company is a either well-exposed, well-known or have lots of apps out in the Top 25 / 50 / x rankings, it **doesn't** mean that they don't release rogue / info farming apps.

In fact, developers who release info farming apps WILL want to have a big name within the App Store to get more people to download their malicious apps. One such case is highlighted in this [article](http://www.engadget.com/2010/07/06/apple-responds-on-itunes-fraud-vaguely-confirms-said-fraud).

A Google search on GetSet games does not reveal any customers flagging them as scammers or info farmers.

A complete list of fradulent apps / app farms cannot be found (heck, it's probably impossible since you'd have to run through all the source code of all the popular apps in the App Store, lest ALL the apps), but here's a small list of such apps can be found [here](http://thenextweb.com/apple/2010/07/05/app-store-app-farm-steal-your-money/).

Answer (score 0):

**[GetSet Games](http://getsetgames.com/)** is a pretty big name on the Appstore, so it's safe to assume that they are a reputable company.  I can tell you I've downloaded Mega Jump, and have never had any problems or concerns with it.  I can't give you a *source*, but I'm positive that it's a secure app.